# Analog-to-digital converters (ADC) and error with least significant bit (LSB)

Tags: electric-circuits, error-analysis, electronics, electrical-engineering

I'm studying analog-to-digital converters (ADC). I have a question about the least significant bit (LSB).
If we have 10 bits and an analog range of 5 V, then the error would be
$$ \frac{5}{2^{10}} = 4.9 \text{mV} \, ,$$
But there are other errors that are all included in LSB.
For example, suppose that I have a 2 LSB error, now the error will be simply 10 mV approximately for all the measure that are between 512 and 1024 (2.5 V and 5 V).

Is this correct?

Comment: A hint about English: only use a question mark ? at the end of a question. A statement such as *"I have a question about LSB"* is not a question and should not have a question mark.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: You can find all the details about ADC/DAC errors in the manufacturer data sheets and application notes. One can easily measure fractions of an LSB with an ADC using techniques like averaging and dithering. One can even get 20 bit resolution out of a one bit ADC using techniques like oversampling and noise shaping, so there is no trivial/short answer to your question to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Errors are not included in LSB. They are shown to you as a multiple of LSB for your convenience.

Quantization error is 0.5LSB, and up to 2LSB error from non-ideal nature of ADC = 2.5LSB total error.

So in the full range (0-1023 / 0V-5V) you can expect up to 5/1024*2.5=12.2mV of error in the worst case, and 0mV in the best case.

Comment: Thanks one more question. If I want to assign an error at the bit that I read, for example 700, how can I do?  I have thought that if I have 2 lsb the error will be $ 2*2^0$ is this correct?